# Calculating $c$ in a piecewise cumulative distribution function

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, cumulative-distribution-functions

[image]

I am struggling to find a means of tackling question (a). Initially I tried to find the original piecewise pdf but this appears to be over complicating the problem. Would it make sense to subtract the $cx^2$ from $1 - c(4-x)^2$ and find the derivative of this and find the derivative of $cx^2$ in order to get the pdf and then integrate over the bounds in order to find $c$?

Comment: Why you don´t set up the equation $F(2^{-})=F(2)$?

Comment: @callculus could you perhaps elaborate on this method? What would $F(2^-)$ be equal to?

Comment: For $F(2^{-})$ you use the cdf where $x<2$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, nothing in the question indicates that the cdf $F(x)$ is continuous, so any $0\leq c\leq \frac18$ is valid. For example, for $c=0$ we get the valid cdf 
$$
F(x)=\begin{cases}0, & x< 2\cr 1, & x\geq 2\end{cases}
$$

If you need to obtain continuous cdf, take left limit at $x=2$ and equate it to the value at $x=2$. You will get $c=\frac18$.

Comment: How could you obtain that $0 \leq c  \leq \frac{1}{8}$ if we don't assume $F(x)$ to be continuous?

Comment: $F$ should be nondecreasing, so its left limit  at $x=2$ must be less or equal to the value at $x=2$. Solve inequality and get upper bound. Why $c$ cannot be negative should be clear.